# Active Record query on first value in stored array on JSONB column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, jsonb

I have a scenario where for an Item, I am logging dates it was 'active_at' into an array stored in a JSONB column.

So the data would look something like this:

```
active_at:
 {"dates"=>
   ["2018-07-22",
    "2018-09-05",
    "2018-09-06",
    "2018-09-07",
    "2018-09-14",
    "2018-09-15",
    "2018-09-16",
    "2018-10-20",
    "2018-10-21",
    "2018-10-30"]}
```

I can successfully query the column as follows for a date match within the array:

```
@item = Item.where('active_at @> ?', {dates: '2018-10-20'.split}.to_json)
```

However, I now need to be able to query for a match on the first entry in the array only. Entries in the array are always in date order as new values are appended to the end of the array.

I have tried things like this, but with no joy:

```
@item = Item.where('active_at @> ?', {dates['first']: '2018-10-20'.split}.to_json)
@item = Item.where('active_at @> ?', {dates.first: '2018-10-20'.split}.to_json)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Item.where("active_at->'dates'->>0 = ?", "2018-10-20")
```

[SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8d75a54c244cea8e96712840419176ce)

I'd be really concerned about the performance of this query and consider doing some schema changes.

Comment: Great! That worked perfectly. I note your concerns about performance, however, this is being used for background reports and is a bit of an edge case.